# Libmemcached creating socket for each get & set request

Tags: c, memcached, libmemcached

I am going through libmemcached 1.0.18 code. One thing I did not understand why it is creating socket for each get & set request? Is there any special reason for that or my assumption is wrong. But in the code I see socket is getting created for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Actually libmemcached does not create sockets for replying to each get and set request for the same server. I overlooked some block of code.